# Alternative of alertdialog.builder.setview for API below 21

Tags: android, android-layout, datepicker, android-alertdialog, android-timepicker

as we know that `alertdialog.builder.setview` function introduces in `API 21` which allow us to set our layout. is there any alternative way to achieve this and i also don't want to use `support library`
[image]

this is what i want to create

hear is the code

and this is `datetime_dialog.xml` file

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <TimePicker
        android:id="@+id/timePicker"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <DatePicker
        android:id="@+id/datePicker"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:calendarViewShown="false" />

</LinearLayout>
```

code of java file

```
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
        MainActivity.this, AlertDialog.THEME_HOLO_DARK);
alertDialogBuilder.setView(R.layout.datetime_dialog);
alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("Done",
        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                // go to a new activity of the app
                Intent positveActivity = new Intent(
                        getApplicationContext(),
                        MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(positveActivity);
            }
        });
// set negative button: No message
alertDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("Cancel",
        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                // cancel the alert box and put a Toast to the
                // user
                dialog.cancel();

            }
        });

AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
// show alert
alertDialog.show();
```

i want to support this upto `API 9` is it possible

Answer (score 1):

You need first to create the View from tha Layout, with:

```
View v = LayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.ID, null);
AlertDialog.Builder ad = new AlertDialog.Builder(Activity);
ad.setview(v);
```